# Run fill-paragraph for content on org-mode export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, fill-paragraph

How can you run fill-paragraph on an exported document?

`fill-paragraph`/`auto-fill-mode` distribute and insert newlines which help when reading a document in an editor that doesn't necessarily wrap long lines automatically.

I don't want to use `auto-fill-mode` because it transforms the org mode content being edited.  I just want exported content to have inserted newlines.

Comment: What are you exporting it to? Most of the export modes do line-wrapping automatically. HTML and LaTeX handle this during rendering, for example. Perhaps there's something similar for the format you're exporting it to.

Comment: I'm exporting org to org presently.  I didn't mention that because I observed org to HTML not line-wrapping.